# Plugging fundamental security vulerabilities in a Django web app

Tags: django, python-2.7, security, http, ssl

I have a Django app which users congregate to, use as a forum and gain reputation points. Majority of the users belong to underserved communities and use primitive, non-js feature phones with proxy browsers such as Opera mini, over low bandwidth internet. Essentially I'm a "Next Billion" digital non-profit.

There are some security vulnerabilities that users can exploit in my forum - I need advice in plugging those. Here are the facts.

There's no SSL certificate installed - all comm. takes place over HTTP. To post in the forum one uses the following piece of code in the django template:

```
<form action="{% url 'private_group_reply' slug=unique %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="unique" value="{{ unique }}">
    <br><span style="color:green;">Image:&nbsp;</span>{{ form.image }}<br>
    <br><span style="color:green;">Comment:</span>{{ form.text }}
    <br>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="OK" id="id_submit">
</form>
```

`unique` is a uuid that identifies which `group` the comment is to be posted in.

The relevant url pattern is: `url(r'^group/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/private/$', auth(PrivateGroupView.as_view()), name='private_group_reply')`

In views.py, the relevant class-based view's method is:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    if self.request.user_banned:
        return redirect("profile", slug=self.request.user.username)
    else:
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        text = f.text
        if text == self.request.user.userprofile.previous_retort:
            redirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')+"#sectionJ")
        else:
            self.request.user.userprofile.previous_retort = text
            self.request.user.userprofile.score = self.request.user.userprofile.score + 2
            self.request.user.userprofile.save()
            #print "image: %s" % f.image
            if f.image:
                image_file = clean_image_file(f.image)
                if image_file:
                    f.image = image_file
                else:
                    f.image = None
            else: 
                f.image = None
            #print "image:%s" % f.image
            which_group = Group.objects.get(unique=self.request.POST.get("unique"))
            reply = Reply.objects.create(writer=self.request.user, which_group=which_group, text=text, image=f.image)
            GroupSeen.objects.create(seen_user= self.request.user,which_reply=reply)
            try:
                return redirect(self.request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER')+"#sectionJ")
            except:
                return redirect("private_group_reply", slug=reply.which_group.unique)
```

---

One particular user is, I think, running a script bot and flooding the group he's a part of, garnering multiple points (each posting is point-incentivized).

Though I'm new to software development, I now have a thriving community on this forum and am thus ramping up my skill-set. I've been reading a ton about SSL security, and rules of thumb any respectable web app ought to follow. What someone can help with currently is this particular case of the flooding user I've described, how to curtail such behavior within my set up. Also any general guidelines to follow will be highly appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance, and please ask for any information you need.

Comment: Off-topic but your nested if needs to return the redirect.. Apart from getting a ssl certificate.. what kind of answer were you looking for? it looks too broad as it stands (to me)..

Comment: Thanks for the off-topic feedback. I don't intend this to be a discussion around SSL - there's a ton of literature out there regarding it. Here, I just want **specific** help regarding how the user flooding my forum could be doing what he/she is doing, how is my code compromised, and is the solution solely to install SSL and change my URL patterns? Lastly, are these even the right questions?

Comment: This isn't anything to do with SSL at all, though. What you're after is XSS, ie cross-site scripting; Django protects you from that by default but perhaps you're bypassing that by marking values as safe where you shouldn't be.

Comment: Are you using the default `is_valid` method, is the CSRF token being ignored?

Comment: @RobL: yes that's a default `form_valid` method under a `CreateView`. And well, all of the method's code is pasted above, I'm not ignoring the CSRF token explicitly anywhere. If I remove `{% csrf_token %}` from the template, I get a 403 Forbidden error, which means it's not being ignored. I also think it's not XSS as Daniel said. This particular form's input isn't marked_safe, and I did the classic `<script>alert('XSS')</script>` test on it (which didn't produce anything untoward).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if its the answer you're looking for but rather than trying to patch up this one part of your code, you probably need to look into creating some rules/regulations on your site along with *penalties* for the users that break this.

If you can prove that a user is doing something against your rules/guidelines, you apply your set penalty (score rollback/bans/whatever) and this would remove the *incentive* for most to even try doing this.

Yes, ssl may help but who knows, and your users will always have the chance to bypass your safeguards.

In terms of the actual code? I wouldn't save the score to the model until everything else has been done. You might also want to make it an atomic transaction to roll back db changes if something goes awry when saving

Comment: Regarding the code, could it then just be that this user is able to sniff all the tokens I pass through POST, since HTTP is not encrypted yet? I'm passing user and group primary keys at various points, and I have heard complaints from various people that the said user is able to sometimes post under their nicknames too (that one's not in the cope of this question). Yep improving rules (SO is a great example) is totally on my radar. I'm thinking up some kind of an anti-flooding logic right now - will be doing research on what's already been done.

Comment: @HassanBaig - Yes, as a very trivial start, it wouldn't be a bad idea to add a timestamp to your model and just check what the user has posted in the last n seconds before allowing them to post again. I'm not sure what method the user had used, maybe codereview.se or security.se have better insights into that (but see their tours for whats acceptable questions)

Comment: @HassanBaig - I've also updated my answer with advice to use `atomic`

Comment: You're implying setting **'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True,** in settings.py under DATABASES?

Comment: @HassanBaig - I was refering more to the [decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.atomic) but either way I guess (I've never used the setting)